# How to add form id using Sitecore or .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, razor, sitecore

I am trying to add the id to a submit form and the codes are written using Sitecore:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
      @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("Payment", "Submit");
    }
```

I have one controller called Payment Controller and uses the submit function inside of the controller. But now I want to add the id to the form, when I try:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null,null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormFinalize" } ))
    {
      @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("Payment", "Submit");
    }
```

It looks like some function breaks.. Anyone has any idea how to correctly add the id to the form? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `some function breaks`? It looks like Sitecore adds id properly when you use your second code snippet

Comment: I highly recommend you not to use this kind of programming in ASP.NET at all. Do not use `razor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need @ sing before the id or any other attribute you need to add like name,class and so on

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null,null, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "FormFinalize" } ))
    {
      @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("Payment", "Submit");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Payment", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormFinalize" } ))
{
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```